# How to scroll using a trackpad in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I'm working on an animation project and I want to zoom in on certain places in the canvas to see better (I don't want to actually zoom in the animation itself" but I can only zoom in and out without scrolling

How can I scroll with my trackpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the alt (option) key on the keyboard, and do a two-finger zoom in the trackpad (make sure you've enabled two-finger zoom in system settings).